# Prove that an operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

how to prove that the operator T on $l^{2}$ is bounded if 
$$
T\{x_{n}\}=\left\{x_{1},\frac{x_{2}+x_{3}}{2!}, \frac{x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{6}}{3!}, \frac{x_{7}+x_{8}+x_{9}+x_{10}}{4!},\ldots \right\}.
$$ Is it possible to factor out $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n!}$ when counting the norm $||T\{x_{n}\}||$? I don't have much profficiency in sequences, so I'd greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: There is no meaningful way to "factor out" that sum of the coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Perhaps surprisingly (given your thoughts so far), we have $\|T\|=1$. Note that
$$
|x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n|^2 \leq n \left(|x_1|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm just not sure what I get if I use this inequality for  ${{||T\{x_{n}\}||}}^{2}=|\left\{x_{1}+\frac{x_{2}+x_{3}}{2!}+ \frac{x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{6}}{3!}+ \frac{x_{7}+x_{8}+x_{9}+x_{10}}{4!}+\ldots \right\}|^{2}\le $?

Comment: @Horseshoecrab99 Are those supposed to be commas instead of plusses?

Comment: @Horseshoecrab99 What do you mean by "I'm not sure what I get"? Did you try to look for a way to apply the inequality that I suggest?